# Bluetooth added to the ListView twice instead once

Tags: android, android-listview, android-bluetooth

I'm searching through available `Bluetooth devices` in range. For some reason, each found device is added to the ListView **twice**, when it should only be shown **once**.

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong here?  Code included below.

> When discovery finds a device

```
if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
   // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
   BluetoothDevice device;
   device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

   // If it's already paired, skip it, because it's been listed already
   if (device.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
      Log.v("test", "test");

      mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
   }

} else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
   // When discovery is finished, change the Activity title

   setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
   setTitle(R.string.select_device);

   if (mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.getCount() == 0) {
      String noDevices = getResources().getText(R.string.none_found).toString();
      mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(noDevices);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code you use the equals operation. that's why it adds the two times. one in already paired device list. And the same items are added again int the newly invented list. Try this code.

```
// When discovery finds a device
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            // If it's already paired, skip it, because it's been listed already
            if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            }
        // When discovery is finished, change the Activity title
        } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
            setTitle(R.string.select_device);
            if (mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.getCount() == 0) {
                String noDevices = getResources().getText(R.string.none_found).toString();
                mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(noDevices);
            }
        }
```

Comment: then also it added two times instead one... i check with both way but getting same result....!!!before == i apply != this but not getting same result...and thanks for your response