# Listview displays duplicate entries of rescanned bluetooth devices

Tags: android, listview, bluetooth

I have an app, which on button (toggle button) press scans and displays discovered bluetooth devices in a custom listview, and on pressing the same button again the scanning is stopped.

Now the problem shows up when I press the button again (2nd time) to start scanning, the same device is shown twice. After I stop and start scanning (3rd time), the same device is shown thrice. And the discovered devices were never paired with my android phone.

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159818/bluetooth-searching-and-adding-in-the-listview-problem), but the answer didn't help me. Please let me know where I have gone wrong.

Below is the code

```
        btOnOff.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(btOnOff.isChecked()){

                btAdapter.startDiscovery();
                setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

                    bcReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                        @Override
                        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            String action = intent.getAction();
                            if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
                                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                                deviceName = device.getName();
                                currentDateTime = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());

                                Custom data = new Custom(deviceName, currentDateTime);
                                fetch.add(data);

                                lv.setAdapter(cAdapter);

                            }else if(btAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)){
                                btAdapter.startDiscovery();
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
                    registerReceiver(bcReceiver, filter);
            } else {
                btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            }
        }

    });
```

I have two more classes which does the customization of listview, could there be anything to avoid the duplicate entries. Below is the code of first class file

```
 public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Custom>{

private ArrayList<Custom> entries;
private Activity activity;

public CustomAdapter(Activity a, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Custom> entries) {
    super(a, textViewResourceId, entries);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.entries = entries;
    this.activity = a;
}

public static class ViewHolder{
    public TextView tv1;
    public TextView tv2;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    View v = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if(v == null){
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.show_devices, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tv1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        holder.tv2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv2);

        v.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();
    }

    final Custom custom = entries.get(position);
    if(custom != null){
        holder.tv1.setText(custom.getFirst());
        holder.tv2.setText(custom.getSecond());
    }
    return v;
}
```

}

The second class file

```
 public class Custom {
private String text1;
private String text2;

public Custom(String string1, String string2){
    this.text1 = string1;
    this.text2 = string2;
}

public String getFirst(){
    return text1;
}

public void setFirst(String text1){
    this.text1 = text1;
}

public String getSecond(){
    return text2;
}

public void setSecond(String text2){
    this.text2 = text2;
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Customizing the listview with the kind of logic used above has created redundancy and duplicate entries are created. So instead of writing custom listview with two additional classes, we could go for the ArrayAdapter with simple_list_item_1.

In the Button onclick event ArrayAdapter object would clear the duplicate entries, and the simple_list_item_1 would provide two rows listview similar to the custom listview.

SImple implementation is show [here](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/05/scan-bluetooth-devices.html)

Answer (score 2):

When you start re-scanning, clear items of your list 'fetch'.. Basically what you do is, every-time you scan, you add bluetooth searched devices to previous list..

Comment: I clear the list using cAdapter.clear(), before I start discovering the devices. The moment scan starts the list gets cleared, but later on the same device is listed with old time stamp.

Comment: so are you trying to say that the list isn't cleared before re-scanning?? it contains elements of previous results??

Comment: The old entries list gets cleared, but on re-scanning the devices are shown with duplicate entries and with SAME time stamp. I've added two more class files, hope if that could help you in figuring out the problem.

Comment: BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
in this line try to change BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE with BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.
May be using EXTRA_DEVICE intent is returning list with old timestamps devices as well as same devices with new timestamps as new entries..

Comment: Application stopped unexpectedly.

Comment: ok.. strange :-s
anyways I have Macbook right now otherwise i'd have checked this behaviour of Bluetooth search in android.. :-s

Comment: i have searched similar posts but I didn't find same problem in any of those in any other post...

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, I will try to debug and find an answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to use the default listview adapter, like you want to display the devices in a dialogfragment or something like that, here is my not so elegant solution to avoid duplicates of the same device appearing when they are re-scanned:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        // When discovery finds a device

        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            if(count ==0){
              prev_device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
              mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
              mArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            Log.d("BLUETOOTH","count = "+count);
            if(!device.getAddress().contains(prev_device.getAddress())){
                Log.d("BLUETOOTH","NOT A MATCH - ADD TO LIST");
            // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
                mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                mArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            prev_device = device;

            if(count ==0){
                showDevices(); //Simply displays a dialogFragment with listview of devices
            }
            count++;
        }
    }
};
```

Basically you check to see if the device was previously scanned. However, this will only work if there is only one device (for my application), but if you need to suit many devices, you would need to store all the previous addresses and parse them like a look up and only display new ones.

Comment: Thanks for the help, my problem was resolved with the answer I posted.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Just put the receiver outside the onclick ,under oncreate.
Since it is under the onclick , receiver is being initialised twice and thus the duplicate devices.

Remove the receiver in the onclick and put it under oncreate

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear list that you use in adapter. like this ->

```
private fun setAdapterToListView() {

        devicesNameAddressList.clear()
        for (i in 0 until devicesName.size) {
            val list = HashMap<String, String>()
            list.put("line1", devicesName[i])
            list.put("line2", devicesAddress[i])
            devicesNameAddressList.add(list)
        }

        val simpleAdapter = SimpleAdapter(this, devicesNameAddressList, R.layout.devices_listview_texttype,
                arrayOf("line1", "line2"), intArrayOf(R.id.line_a, R.id.line_b))
        BluetoothDevicesListID.adapter = simpleAdapter
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For bluetooth device has mac address, You can match mac address and remove duplicate device from list.